# How can i handle the page crash in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6.2

Whenever i leave my website for like 1 hour and whenever i try to access the different part of the website i get **"Trying to get property 'id of non object"**, it means that the user have been logged out but the page crashed.

So i need a way so that i can apply a middleware to handle this issue??

can anyone help me??

[image]'

Comment: The exception is being thrown on line 65 of the `DashboardController.php` but your screenshot doesn't show that line. You'll need to post that for context for us to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that it is caused by user logged out due to session, you can apply a global middleware (applied to all route, or just the default auth middleware), to check if they are still logged in, and if they are not, you can redirect them back to login page. Something simply like this

```
if (Auth::user()){
    return $next($request);
}
return redirect($yourLoginRoute);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In your route file web.php you can use middleware auth, it will be redirect user to login page. For example see my code:

```
Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@index')->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score -3):

reboot I guess!!
facing this issue has only one solution you should always try rebooting your PC and your brain